# Route celery tasks

Tags: celery, django-celery

In some Django-project there are tasks:

```
@app.task
def task1():
    # processing


@app.task
def task2():
    # processing


@app.task
def long_task():
    # very long processing
```

`settings.py`:

```
default_exchange = Exchange('default', type='direct')

CELERY_QUEUES = (
    Queue(
        name='celery',  # should I define default queue?
        exchange=default_exchange
    ),
    Queue(
        name='long',
        exchange=default_exchange
    )
)
CELERY_ROUTES = {
    'long_task': {
        'queue': 'long'
    },
}
```

With this all tasks that are ran like this:

```
long.apply_async()
```

are being sent to default queue.

How sent them to different queues?

Answer (score 0):

Defined a queue name in decorator:

```
@app.task(queue='long')
def long_task():
    # very long processing
```

And ran worker in a separate pod.